# How to add background-image change to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already have the following jQuery to add an accordion-like feature to my mobile view, making the charts open and close on click:

```
$('.home-widget h3.widget-title').on('click', function(){

    if(window.matchMedia){
        if(window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 1024px)").matches == true) {
            if($(this).next("div.widget-body").css('display') == "none"){
                $(this).next("div.widget-body").css('display', 'block');
                $(this).parent("div.widget").css('min-height', '648px');
                drawWidgets()
                redrawCharts();
                redrawDatatables();
            }else{
                $(this).next("div.widget-body").css('display', 'none');
                $(this).parent("div.widget").css('min-height', 'auto');
                drawWidgets()
                redrawCharts();
                redrawDatatables();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have a background-image applied to my 'widget-title', which I would like to change from a plus (+) to a minus (-) when the 'widget-body' is displayed. Could anyone tell me where I would add this to the jQuery provided?

CSS is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WMHJ.png).

Comment: Please add some `html/css` code to show us your problem. You can create a "snippet" for this. (_CTRL+M_)

Comment: CSS has been added. HTML is a little more tricky to add, as it comes from multiple places. It basically just shows widget-title and widget-body, pulling the data from relevant places.. I believe it shouldn't affect the jQuery though.

Comment: You should really have a look on this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apologies, the code that I am working with is not the easiest, so it is difficult to explain my problem. I would like a jQuery statement adding into the above that changes an element of my CSS in 'widget-title' (background-image) to a different image when the max screen width = 1024px and 'widget-body' display = block. Does this help? :)

Comment: Since you're applying the background image with css, create another class for the "minus" state. You can then use jQuery's toggleClass method to switch between the two when you open/close the accordion.

Comment: I have tried that but also had no luck! I wonder if it is conflicting with the other jquery above, as I have been adding this as a separate script with no luck..

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I have understood you.

```
if($(this).next("div.widget-body").css('display') == "none"){
    $('.widget-title').css('background-image','url(img/1.jpg)');
}else{
    $('.widget-title').css('background-image','url(img/2.jpg)');
}
```

Comment: I think it's along the right lines, but how would I change my background-image within that jQuery? I have added my css to the question.

Comment: I have edited my answer with jquery code to change background image. You just need to change source to the images.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't seem to do anything at all. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it like this?

```js
if ($(window).width() < 1024 && $('.widget-title').is(":visible")) {

  $('.widget-title').css('background-image', 'url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Google_Chrome_for_Android_Icon_2016.svg")');
  
} else {

  $('.widget-title').css('background-image', 'url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a")');
  
}
```

```css
.widget-title {
 height: 200px;
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-title">Testing</div>
```

Just try this snippet when you click on "Run code snippet" before you click on "Expand snippet", close it, "Expant snippet" and then "Run code snippet".

You could also create a new `class` for the `background` and just add the `class` to the `div`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your suggestion but with no luck. I then tried:

    $('.home-widget h3').click(function(){
  $('home-widget h3').removeClass('.widget-title').addClass('.widget-title2');
 });

Unfortunately this did not make a difference either..